# Having problems with nginx in openwrt

Tags: nginx, openwrt, reverse-proxy

I have a router with external ip xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa with openwrt installed on it. It also has nginx package installed. I also has a web server with internal ip aaa.bbb.ccc.eee, connected to router's lan. Now i want to see my site project.com available on the web. Of course, i can use port forwarding and not to use nginx, but in future i want to have one more web server with more sites. So, nginx is necessary for me.

My nginx is started and it has these config files:

cat **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**:

```
user nobody nogroup;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    #default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf
```

cat **/etc/nginx/conf.d/project.com.conf**:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name project.com;
location / {
proxy_pass http://aaa.bbb.ccc.eee;
proxy_cache off;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_redirect off;
charset off;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarder-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

But my site project.com is anavailable. Services httpd and nginx are running on aaa.bbb.ccc.eee server. Where is a mistake in my configs?

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

The line "*include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf*" should be "*include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;*" and it also should be inside **http { }** section.
There were some errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log about this. Now i fixed this, no errors are shown in error.log, but **still not works**...

p.s. my uhttpd (used for LUCI) port is 8080, so it does not conflicts with nginx's 80 port. Don't know what to do else (

Comment: and my **netstat -plant | grep 80**,by the way, now is
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12214/nginx.conf -g
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12143/uhttpd
tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      12143/uhttpd`